# How to spool explain results from Oracle via sqlplus?

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm having issues with spooling out results from queries, more or less it shows always no real cost, shows rows as one and no cost or anything added, and not the statistics of the actual query.

I'm using this setup:

```
current_date=$(date +%Y-%m-%d)
sqlplus -S "Username/password@mydatabase.bag" <<EOF >/output/Testoutput_$current_date.log
set verify off;
set colsep ,
SET AUTOTRACE ON
set headsep off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set termout off
col v_spool noprint new_value v_spool
select 'Spoolfile'||
to_char(sysdate,'yyyy_mm_dd_hh24_mi_ss')||'.csv' v_spool from dual;
set termout on
spool /folder/subfolder/&&v_spool
set lines 12345 pages 12345;
EXPLAIN PLAN SET statement_id = 'example_plan1' FOR
select * from dbms.database1_1 where numberline like '%4214%';
SET TIMING OFF
spool off
EXIT
EOF
```

My wish is to somehow get the explain results spooled to a file, what do I need to modify to achieve this or there is a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try running this in SQL*Plus:

```
EXPLAIN PLAN SET statement_id = 'example_plan1' FOR
select * from dbms.database1_1 where numberline like '%4214%';
```

You'll notice that it just outputs:

```
Explained.
```

You have to actually select the results of the EXPLAIN PLAN using DBMS_XPLAN - that will get output and spooled to your file.

```
-- generate the explain plan
EXPLAIN PLAN SET statement_id = 'example_plan1' FOR
  select * from dbms.database1_1 where numberline like '%4214%';
-- actually display the results
select plan_table_output 
  from table(dbms_xplan.display('plan_table',null,'typical'));
```

Comment: Question on same matter, how would it look like if I had lets say multiple files with queries to parse? considering each run out have output with different timestamp.

Thank you!

Comment: @EXO - I'm not sure what you mean. Are you trying to read multiple files, and each one has a query that you want an explain plan for? That seems possible, but you might want to create a new question for it.

Comment: Yes, exactly :)